# How to set custom DelegatingHandler to all HttpClients automatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I would like to use the LoggingHttpClientHandler for all the clients in the application. I found the only usable way via named/typed client

**startup.cs**

```
services.AddTransient<LoggingHttpClientHandler>();
services.AddHttpClient("clientWithLogging").AddHttpMessageHandler<LoggingHttpClientHandler>();
```

and then in each service I have to use `var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("clientWithLogging")` which is kinda uncomfortable.

**LoggingHttpClientHandler.cs**

```
public class LoggingHttpClientHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public LoggingHttpClientHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler) : base(innerHandler)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.Content != null)
        {
            Logging.Log.Info(await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Is there a way how to do it without naming each client?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add HTTP message handler to all HTTP clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64103349/add-http-message-handler-to-all-http-clients)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was with resolving of params in useless constructor of `LoggingHttpClientHandler`.
So I removed the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

If it is just about the name, there is an extension method [CreateClient](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/HttpClientFactory/Http/src/HttpClientFactoryExtensions.cs) that takes no arguments and uses the default name, which is [string.Empty](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Options/Options/src/Options.cs).
So you might be fine by registering the service using `string.Empty` as name, e.g.:

```
services.AddHttpClient(string.Empty)
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<LoggingHttpClientHandler>();
```

and instantiate clients using:

```
var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
```

Comment: If I do it, I got `'Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler' while attempting to activate 'MyNamespace.LoggingHttpClientHandler'.'`

Comment: Or if I do not use the `AddTransient` line, it says `'No service for type 'MyNamespace.LoggingHttpClientHandler' has been registered.'`