# Add HTTP message handler to all HTTP clients

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have an HTTP message handler named `AddHeadersHandler`, which extends `System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler` and I need it to be added to all current and future `HttpClient` instances, including typed, named and non-named clients.

I know I can add a handler using `.AddHttpMessageHandler<AddHeadersHandler>()` for a specific client, but how do I add it to all clients?

```cs
// AddHeadersHandler.cs
public class AddHeadersHandler: DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-Correlation-Id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

```cs
// Startup.cs
services
    .AddHttpContextAccessor()
    .AddTransient<AddHeadersHandler>();
services
    .AddHttpClient<MyClient>()
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<AddHeadersHandler>(); // I don't want to specify this for each client.
```

```cs
// MyClient.cs
public class MyClient
{
    public HttpClient HttpClient { get; }

    public MyClient(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        HttpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task GetTest()
    {
        await HttpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:5001/test"); // This should have headers attached.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It can be done by configuring `HttpClientFactoryOptions` for **all named** options. We need to provide a delegate in `HttpMessageHandlerBuilderActions`, which will include your handler to `AdditionalHandlers` property list.

There are multiple ways of doing this using the [Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options) pattern:

## 1. Using `.AddSingleton()` ❌

If your handler has any dependencies (e.g. `IHttpContextAccessor` to get current correlation id), we would like to use dependency injection to resolve it.

We could use the [OptionsBuilder API](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options#optionsbuilder-api) to get a required handler using dependency injection. Unfortunately, this API does not provide a method to configure options **for all named** instances like `.ConfigureAll` does.

Luckily, we can get what we need by registering a factory method for `IConfigureOptions<HttpClientFactoryOptions>` like so:

```cs
// Startup.cs
services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<HttpClientFactoryOptions>>(
    provider =>
    {
        // When name is null, these options will be used for all clients.
        return new ConfigureNamedOptions<HttpClientFactoryOptions>(
            name: null,
            options =>
            {
                options.HttpMessageHandlerBuilderActions.Add(builder =>
                {
                    // Here we have access to ServiceProvider
                    // to get an instance of the handler.
                    builder.AdditionalHandlers.Add(
                        provider.GetRequiredService<AddHeadersHandler>());
                });
            });
    });
```

## 2. Using `.ConfigureAll()` ✔️

*The following improved answer was inspired by [LostInComputer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/522254/lostincomputer).*

Add `.ConfigureAll` in your `Startup.cs` and use `IServiceProvider` through the builder like so:

```cs
services.ConfigureAll<HttpClientFactoryOptions>(options =>
{
    options.HttpMessageHandlerBuilderActions.Add(builder =>
    {
        builder.AdditionalHandlers.Add(builder.Services
            .GetRequiredService<AddHeadersHandler>());
    });
});
```

Comment: This configure all should be added before or after the AddHttpClient method?

Comment: @LuizBicalho, order should not be important as long as it is within the same `ServiceCollection`.