# Is it possible to call async method in Blazor WASM when configuring named HttpClient?

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to setup named HttpClient in Blazor WASM. Problem is that I need to call async method in order to get JWT.

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("auth", async c =>
    {
        // access the DI container
        var serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
        // Find the HttpContextAccessor service
        var localStorageService = serviceProvider.GetService<ILocalStorageService>();
        // Get the bearer token.
        if (localStorageService == null) return;
        
        var jwt = await localStorageService.GetJwtAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("JWT "+jwt);
        if (jwt != null)
        {
            c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", jwt);
        }
    }
);
```

This doesn't work since parameter **c** cannot be async function.

Next I tried something like this

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("auth", c =>
    {
        // access the DI container
        var serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
        // Find the HttpContextAccessor service
        var localStorageService = serviceProvider.GetService<ILocalStorageService>();
        // Get the bearer token.
        if (localStorageService == null) return;
        
        var jwt = localStorageService.GetJwtAsync().Result;
        Console.WriteLine("JWT "+jwt);
        if (jwt != null)
        {
            c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", jwt);
        }
    }
);
```

In this case I get an error

> Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot wait on monitors on this runtime

because I am using `.Result` in WASM and it is blocking the main thread.

Any ideas is this possible to implement and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider writing a custom [`DelegatingHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.delegatinghandler?view=net-7.0).

A `DelegatingHandler` is a decorator that can be used to add behavior before or after the inner Http Handler will be called by overriding the `SendAsync` method.

In your case the handler could look like in the example below:

```cs
public class LocalStorageAuthHandler : DelegatingHandler
{  
    private readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorageService;
  
    public LocalStorageAuthHandler(ILocalStorageService localStorageService)
    {
         _localStorageService = localStorageService;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Access local storage service and update headers accordingly
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Then add the handler to your `HttpClient`:

```cs
// Transient, Scoped or Singleton depends on your code:
services.AddTransient<LocalStorageAuthHandler>();
services.AddHttpClient("clientName")
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<LocalStorageAuthHandler>();
```

This will use the `LocalStorageAuthHandler` with the default http message handler as inner handler.

You can even combine multiple `DelegatingHandler`s to build a *Chain of Responsibility*.

See [Make HTTP requests using IHttpClientFactory in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#outgoing-request-middleware) on Microsoft Learn for details.

Comment: Thanks, works great! You have one mistake though, it should be "return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);" instead of "return await SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);". It creates recursive function that never ends.

Comment: And constructor name should be "LocalStorageAuthHandler" instead of "CustomHandler". Leaving this in comment just in case someone else wants to use this with copy-paste style

Comment: Glad it helped :) Fixed the errors in my Answer.

Comment: I used this answer but needed to use it with HttpClientFactory for all HttpClient instances (for use with NSwag).  I found that combining the above answer with the following answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64103349/add-http-message-handler-to-all-http-clients
Gave me exactly what I needed.